# Fast assessment of corrupted Affymetrix CEL files

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I'm trying to normalize a big amount of Affymetrix CEL files using R. However, some of them appear to be truncated, so when reading them i get the error

```
Cel file xxx does not seem to have the correct dimensions
```

And the normalization stops. Manually removing the corrupted files and restart every time will take very long. Do you know if there is a fast way (in R or with a tool) to detect corrupted files?

PS I'm 99.99% sure I'm normalizing together CELs from the same platform, it's really just truncated files :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One simple suggestion:

Can you just use a tryCatch block around your read.table (or whichever read command you're using)?  Then just skip a file if you get that error message.  You can also compile a list of corrupted files within the catch block (I recommend doing that so that you are tracking corrupted files for future reference when running a big batch process like this).  Here's the pseudo code:

```
corrupted.files <- data.frame()
for(i in 1:nrow(files)) {
    x <- tryCatch(read.table(file=files[i]), error = function(e) 
         if(e=="something") { corrupted.files <- rbind(corrupted.files, files[i]) } 
         else { stop(e) }, 
       finally=print(paste("finished with", files[i], "at", Sys.time())))
    if(nrow(x)) # do something with the uncorrupted data            
}
```

Comment: Not bad thanks :-) It works for removing corrupted files. (To read them, I use a specific ReadAffy function from BioConductor, but that's ok).
I still need something to check the name of the platform, but that is something for a bioconductor forum maybe.